# Understanding Unity 5 Car controller

Tags: c#, unity

As with all Unity versions Unity 5 comes with a set of Standard Assets. This new set of Standard Assets comes with a Car Controller. Either by attaching a Car user controller script or a Car A.I. script the Car is ready to be used within a game. I am using that said Car controller to create my own car in a game. What I am trying to do is increase the cars acceleration and top speed. I did not find any documentation on the mechanics behind the car controller (and since I do not know much about cars) I did not find a way on how to do this. I am reading the script and understand the flow of code but do not understand which variables affect what in the script.

Now for Top speed the car controller exposes a public variable responsible for that precise task.
But what about acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to increase the car's acceleration, you need to increase the torque variable.
There are two torque variables in Unity's official car controller, one for the forward movement and one for the reverse.

Keep in mind that the torque variable also controls how gears change (f.e. more torque = earlier gear changes) and too low of a torque can make certain speeds pretty hard to attain.

Comment: Hmm, one of the problems I do not understand much about actual cars :D
Thanks

Comment: After Testing it a bit more I increased the Full Torque on four wheels variable from 2500 to 4000 and no change in speed has been made. Also I  tried reducing the mass of the car from 1000 to 500 and still nothing

Comment: Also for some reason, when moving forward the car tilts a bit to the left (turns left even though only W is pressed)

Answer (score -1):

I've found it. You need to change the reverse torque ;) and wheel colliders forward friction.